# How to output the Ruby class name wrapped around Singleton method

Tags: ruby

My goal is:

```
class Bermuda
  class << self
    def grass
      puts self.superclass.name
    end
  end
end

# my goal is that this expression
Bermuda.grass 

# will output a string of the class name it resides in
=> "Bermuda"
```

I cannot display the name of the class that holds a singleton method. I have tried a number of different stabs and standard library searches but haven't found an answer.

This is partially pointless because you would not need a class method to display the information that you would need in the first place to call that method. I'm curious if it's possible or I'm completely missing the scope.

Comment: when I run your code, it return `Object`
`Bermuda.grass # => Object`

Comment: Yes sorry I meant my goal is the output of the string "Bermuda".

Comment: So you can using `self.class.name`

Comment: When I run this in IRB I just get Class => nil as an output for some reason.

Comment: @IanB. Read my answer to find why you get that output.

Comment: @IanB. I don't care what answer you choose, but you should at least read the points I've made. Writing a method that only calls another method, instead of simply calling that other method, is usually never the answer. If you do this, you'll only obfuscate your code. There are better practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call `name` on `self`

```
class Bermuda
  class << self
    def grass
      puts self.name
    end
  end
end
```

This sort of an implementation isn't recommended since all you have to do to get the class name is call `Bermuda.name`

Please see the answer given below by @MatthewCliatt for more info.

Comment: If you could call this method, you would call it like `Bermuda.grass`, since it does the same thing as `Bermuda.name` or `Bermuda.class.name`, why wouldn't you use one of those methods?

Comment: Firstly let me correct you there, `Bermuda.class.name` will always return `Class` and `Bermuda.name` is what's required

Comment: @MatthewCliatt The question was never to write something useful. As it was already pointed out in the question. `I understand this is partially pointless` So could you care to explain why my answer was downvoted.

Comment: Thanks dude, was way overthinking that one!

Comment: @Alfie Well hello Mr. Attitude. It doesn't matter what Bermuda.class returns, my point is that it's useless to make a method which only calls a built in method that could have been called to begin with. [This](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/%E2%80%98first%E2%80%99-or-%E2%80%98firstly%E2%80%99) is a nice read by the way.

Comment: Yes i agree it's not useful, it was never meant to be.

Comment: Then at least let the author know that you're leading them down a dangerous path of poor practices and bad decisions. If you're going to provide a bad way of doing something, and you know it is not the right way of doing something, then show them the right way.

Comment: Ok, there you go. Updated

Comment: Alfie answered the question exactly how I asked it. Your answer was self-indulgent and not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as:

```
self.class.name
```

But, the catch is that this isn't for class methods, it's for instance methods.
That means you don't declare it with `self`. This was your code:

```
class Bermuda
  class << self
    def grass
      puts self.superclass.name
    end
  end
end
```

And that will make the `grass` method a class method. You would have to call it like `Bermuda.grass`.
But, if you can call class methods like the one above, you could just as easily write: `Bermuda.name`.

I'm assuming you can't call class methods, probably because you're working with an instance. So you want to write this method as such:

```
class Bermuda
  def grass
    puts self.class.name
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you're creating a singleton method, but I don't think your method is a singleton method in the usual sense (i.e. a method on an object that is an instance of a class, but not itself a class).

I believe the `class << self` notation you use merely results in a class method being defined, identical to:

```
def self.grass
  puts name
end

In irb:

2.3.0 :003 > class Bermuda; def self.grass; puts name; end; end
 => :grass
2.3.0 :004 > Bermuda.grass
Bermuda
```